# Emacs auto-complete not displaying results

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I am running the most recent version of `auto-complete` in `elpa` with the new stable release of Emacs (24.3) in Linux.  I have the following setup on my Emacs init file.

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(setq-default ac-sources
          '(
        ac-source-filename
        ac-source-abbrev 
        ac-source-dictionary
        ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
(ac-config-default)
```

If I start typing: `/home/james/.em` **in a buffer** (e.g. a Python buffer) I would expect auto-complete to suggest:

```
.emacs
.emacs.d
```

but it does not show anything. The same thing happens with other files.

Sometimes I **do** see suggestions and/or the pop-up menu shows up, but other times it doesn't.

Any thoughts why?

Comment: Where are you typing `/home/james/.em`? I don't think autocomplete works in the minibuffer. Maybe you are looking for `M-x ido-mode`?

Comment: Thanks @Ista. It's on a python buffer (although I tried other buffers, such as a buffer with `.emacs`). I updated the OP

Comment: did you looked for `ido-mode`?

Comment: @ArpitRawat I use [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) (formerly known as anything)  instead. But why does that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ac-config-default` sets a list of sources that does not include ac-source-filename. By calling this function after `setq-default ac-sources` you are resetting them back to the defaults. The [auto-complete manual suggests](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Using_Source) setting mode-hooks to set up the desired sources for specific modes. The example from the manual is

```
(defun my-ac-emacs-lisp-mode ()
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-symbols ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-ac-emacs-lisp-mode)
```

Adapting this to python-mode should be easy enough. Alternatively you can globally override the settings set by `ac-config-default` by calling it first, i.e.

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(setq-default ac-sources
          '(
        ac-source-filename
        ac-source-abbrev 
        ac-source-dictionary
        ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
```

That way `setq-default ac-sources` will override the sources set by `ac-config-default` rather than the other way around.